# return quoted variable inside function with input z without quote in R

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is return z to the filter within a function so I can get x y value of z
but I failed to do so as it the name == should be "z"
is there anyway I can return "z" to from the input z within the function? or i have to do it on other way?

```
findD = function(x,y,z){
  ax = data %>% filter(name == z ) %>% select(x col)
  ay = data %>% filter(name == z ) %>% select(y col)
  dy = ay*y
  dx = ax-x
  d = dy*dx
  return(abs(d))
}
```

Comment: give input ````val = 'z'; findD(x,y,val)```` does it help? excuse me, the function contains, ````data, ay, ax```` take of these objects.

Comment: ay ax should be x of z and y of z

Comment: I tried but it just returned the value `z` in the `val`

Comment: do you have sample data? and required output of the function?